# When I use a NSMutableArray which as a property of a Singleton , to add some object into the NSMutableArray. It crushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here is my sampleCode :

```
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender {
//ShoppingManager sharedManager is a singleton
[[ShoppingManager sharedManager].onlineClassArray addObject:@(1)];
}
```

and code in ShoppingManager.m:

```
//singleton
+ (ShoppingManager *)sharedManager{
    static id instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc]init];
    });
    return instance;
}


- (OnlineClassItemizeArray *)onlineClassArray{
    if (!_onlineClassArray) {
        _onlineClassArray = [OnlineClassItemizeArray array];
    }
    return _onlineClassArray;
}
```

and the ShoppingMananger.h:

```
@interface ShoppingManager : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong) OnlineClassItemizeArray * onlineClassArray;
+ (ShoppingManager*)sharedManager;
@end
```

I don't know what is wrong with these codes.when i added some object into the mutableArray,it stopped at this line:(a all Exception BreakPoint)

```
  _onlineClassArray = [OnlineClassItemizeArray array];
```

than crushed at here:

```
DISPATCH_INLINE DISPATCH_ALWAYS_INLINE DISPATCH_NONNULL_ALL DISPATCH_NOTHROW
DISPATCH_SWIFT3_UNAVAILABLE("Use lazily initialized globals instead")
void
_dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate,
        DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
        dispatch_once(predicate, block);//<---crushed here
    } else {
        dispatch_compiler_barrier();
    }
    DISPATCH_COMPILER_CAN_ASSUME(*predicate == ~0l);
}
```

and here is the whole error msg:

```
  2017-03-14 01:01:36.586 tesr1111[7075:1333259] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[OnlineClassItemizeArray initWithCapacity:]!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001100c4d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fb2621e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101357df __CFRequireConcreteImplementation + 255
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101241a7 -[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:] + 39
    4   tesr1111                            0x000000010f54e6d0 -[ShoppingManager init] + 160
    5   tesr1111                            0x000000010f54e5f1 __32+[ShoppingManager sharedManager]_block_invoke + 65
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112eda0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112ebf1f8 dispatch_once_f + 501
    8   tesr1111                            0x000000010f54e588 +[ShoppingManager sharedManager] + 136
    9   tesr1111                            0x000000010f54de9d -[ViewController add:] + 61
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001104ea8bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110670c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000110670f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    13  UIKit                               0x000000011066fe4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000110558545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110559c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001105069ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000120cca481 -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 93
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000110cf372d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000110cec463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110069761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011004e98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011004de76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011004d884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113eb0a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001104e8c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    26  tesr1111                            0x000000010f54e4df main + 111
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112f2668d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If anyone can give me any idea or helping link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error if it crashes? What's `OnlineClassItemizeArray` exactly?

Comment: i had update the question and show where it crushed. the Xcode showed some error like: `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception` but i have no idear what dose those error means.    and yes the `OnlineClassItemizeArray ` is exactly.

Comment: ` terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception'` do you have the whole error message? Please share it and add it to your question.

Comment: ok,i had paste the whole error msg to the question.

Comment: You need to show the code of `OnlineClassItemizeArray`.

Comment: i write noting but `#import "OnlineClassItemizeArray.h"
@implementation OnlineClassItemizeArray
@end` in the `OnlineClassItemizeArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subclassing `NSMutableArray` incorrectly.  It is a class cluster and there is a minimum set of methods that need to be implemented.

In this case, you are calling `initWithCapacity:` but haven't overridden that method.   Or, more likely, you are calling a generic method (`init`) that calls through to that method.

Exactly as the exception says:

*2017-03-14 01:01:36.586 tesr1111[7075:1333259] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: **' -[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[OnlineClassItemizeArray initWithCapacity:]!'***

However, subclassing the collection classes is a `code smell`.  It is pretty much never done.   There are rare cases where it makes sense;  what is yours?

Comment: thanks a lot. i solve the problem by changing the `onlineClassItemizeArray` 's class form [OnlineClassItemizeArray class] to [NSMutableArray Class]. but i still don't understand , the  [OnlineClassItemizeArray class]  is inheritance form NSMutableArray like :`@interface OnlineClassItemizeArray : NSMutableArray` why it crushed when i use [OnlineClassItemizeArray class]?

Comment: `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are part of a *class cluster*.  When you instantiate an `NSMutableArray`, you actually get a subclass as the instance.  That subclass implements all the primitive methods that `NSMutableArray` requires.  Your subclass does not implement all the primitive methods;  `initWithCapacity:`, specifically.